# How to assign a color to a variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of species that I have to color code based on taxonomic grouping and I'm not sure how to.

Here is the list:

Homo sapiens - human being Mus musculus - house mouse  Danio rerio - zebrafish Drosophila melanogaster - fruit fly Xenopus tropicalis - tree frog S. cerevisiae - budding yeast Arabidopsis thaliana Oryza sativa - Rice Populus trichocarpa - Cottonwood (poplar tree)

Here is the code I have so far:

```r
    install.packages("devtools")
    library(devtools)
    install_github("aloraine/loralib")
    library(loralib)
    genes=getGeneLengthsForPanel()
    medians=getMedianGeneLengthsForPanel(genes)
    sizes=getGenomeSizesForPanel()/10**6
    main="Gene length and genome size"
    xlab="genome sizes (Mb)"
    ylab="log10(median gene length)"
    xlim=c(0,4000)


    plot(medians~sizes,pch=16,xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,las=1,col="lightblue",main=main,xlim=xlim)
            text(medians~sizes,labels=names(medians),cex=0.9,font=2,pos=4)
            old.par=par(no.readonly=TRUE)
            par(mar=c(5.1,7.5,4.1,2.1))
            boxplot(log10length~species,data=genes,las=1,horizontal=TRUE,xlab=ylab)
            par(old.par)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are looking for. Are you looking for a way to color your boxplot according to a specific variable?

Comment: Yes I believe so. For example I would like to just assign Homo sapiens to the the color orange and have only that boxplot be orange. Then I can do that for the entire list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To color the boxplot you need to pass a vector of colors as `col`. There are several way to proceed, if you want to use the column `species`, one way is to use the unique levels of your this column (cause `species` is of class `factor`):

```
boxplot(log10length~species, data=genes, las=1, horizontal=TRUE, xlab=ylab, col = as.numeric(unique(genes$species)))
```

If you do so, and if you use the default color palette, you will realize that `species` as 9 levels whereas the default palette as only 8 colors and so black will be used twice. In order to custom the palette, you can use `palette()` and use the color vector you want: you can use hexadecimal code for color or any color name you can see using `colors()` (see https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/color/ for more details). For instance, you can use the following.

```
palette(c("orange", "grey50", "brown2", "#eecd40", "darkgreen", "#26adba", "#4665e7", "#fa7fd0", "#a61932"))
boxplot(log10length~species, data=genes, las=1, horizontal=TRUE, xlab=ylab, col = as.numeric(unique(genes$species)))
```

Note that the order of the color will dependent on the order of the levels of the factor. Alternatively, you can directly use the vector of color in `boxplot`

```
boxplot(log10length~species, data=genes, las=1, horizontal=TRUE, xlab=ylab, col = c("orange", "grey50", "brown2", "#eecd40", "darkgreen", "#26adba", "#4665e7", "#fa7fd0", "#a61932"))
```

Finally, there are package that provide color palette, e.g. [RColorBrewer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! this was so helpful

Comment: Happy this was helpful :)!